# How to sort in ascending order the solution vector in each iteration using ODE?

Tags: matlab, ode

I've got an ODE system working perfectly. But now, I want in each iteration, sort in ascending order the solution vector. I've tried many ways but I could not do it. Does anyone know how to do?

Here is a simplified code:

```
function dtemp = tanque1(t,temp)
  for i=1:N
    if i==1
      dtemp(i)=(((-k(i)*At*(temp(i)-temp(i+1)))/(y))-(U*As(i)*(temp(i)-Tamb)))/(ro(i)*vol_nodo*cp(i));
    end
    if i>1 && i<N
      dtemp(i)=(((k(i)*At*(temp(i-1)-temp(i)))/(y))-((k(i)*At*(temp(i)-temp(i+1)))/(y))-(U*As(i)*(temp(i)-Tamb)))/(ro(i)*vol_nodo*cp(i));
    end
    if i==N
      dtemp(i)=(((k(i)*At*(temp(i-1)-temp(i)))/(y))-(U*As(i)*(temp(i)-Tamb)))/(ro(i)*vol_nodo*cp(i));
    end
  end
end
```

Test Script:

```
inicial=343.15*ones(200,1);
[t temp]=ode45(@tanque1,0:360:18000,inicial);
```

Comment: I'm unclear on why you would sort the solution vector, this would seem to make your solution unusable.  Sorry I don't understand.  Why do you want to sort the solution vector?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have three different sets of differential equations depending on the index `i` of the solution vector. I don't think you mean "sort," but rather a more efficient way to implement what you've already done - basically vectorization. Provided I haven't accidentally made any typos (you should check), the following should do what you need:

```
function dtemp = tanque1(t,temp)
    dtemp(1) = (-k(1)*At*(temp(1)-temp(2))/y-U*As(1)*(temp(1)-Tamb))/(ro(1)*vol_nodo*cp(1));
    dtemp(2:N-1) = (k(2:N-1).*(diff(temp(1:N-1))-diff(temp(2:N)))*At/y-U*As(2:N-1).*(temp(2:N-1)-Tamb))./(vol_nodo*ro(2:N-1).*cp(2:N-1));
    dtemp(N) = (k(N)*At*(temp(N-1)-temp(N))/y-U*As(N)*(temp(N)-Tamb))/(ro(N)*vol_nodo*cp(N));
```

You'll still need to define `N` and the other parameters and ensure that `temp` is returned as a column vector. You could also try replacing `N` with the `end` keyword, which might be faster. The two uses of [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) make the code shorter, but, depending on the value of `N`, they may also speed up the calculation. They could be replaced with `temp(1:N-2)-temp(2:N-1)` and `temp(2:N-1)-temp(3:N)`. It may be possible to collapse these down to a single vectorized equation, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to attempt if you like.

Note that I also removed a great many unnecessary parentheses for clarity. As you learn Matlab you'll to get used to the [order of operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-38155) and figure out when parentheses are needed.